# Remove Hashes in R Output from R Markdown and Knitr

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I am using RStudio to write my R Markdown files.  How can I remove the hashes (`##`) in the final HTML output file that are displayed before the code output?

As an example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
head(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: It's worth considering the purpose of the hashes. They make it easy for R code to be copied and pasted from your document into R console, because the R output is commented out by the hashes and so will be ignored.

Comment: You can also `command + shift + c` on a mac or `control + shift + c` on a pc to remove the hashtags if you need

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can include in your chunk options something like

```
comment=NA # to remove all hashes
```

or

```
comment='%' # to use a different character
```

More help on knitr available from here: http://yihui.name/knitr/options

If you are using R Markdown as you mentioned, your chunk could look like this:

````
```{r comment=NA}
summary(cars)
```
````

If you want to change this globally, you can include a chunk in your document:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)
```
````

Comment: If you want to remove hashes from all output, you can set `opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)`.

Comment: And if you want the result to show up as if it wasn't code at all but rather regular text, you can use `results='asis'`, and `comment` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Ramnath you should probably mention that in order for this to work you need to add `library(knitr)` to the cell.

Answer (score 4):

## Just HTML

If your output is just HTML, you can make good use of the PRE or CODE HTML tag.

### Example

````
```{r my_pre_example,echo=FALSE,include=TRUE,results='asis'}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)
cat('<pre>')
print(t.test(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$wt))
cat('</pre>')
```
````

### HTML Result:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test
```

data:  mtcars$mpg and mtcars$wt
   t = 15.633, df = 32.633, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
   alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
   95 percent confidence interval:
    14.67644 19.07031
   sample estimates:
   mean of x mean of y 
    20.09062   3.21725

## Just PDF

If your output is PDF, then you may need some replace function. Here what I am using:

````
```r
tidyPrint <- function(data) {
    content <- paste0(data,collapse = "\n\n")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\t","    ")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\ ","\\\\ ")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\$","\\\\$")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\*","\\\\*")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,":",": ")
    return(content)
  }
```
````

### Example

The code also needs to be a little different:

````
```{r my_pre_example,echo=FALSE,include=TRUE,results='asis'}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)
resultTTest <- capture.output(t.test(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$wt))
cat(tidyPrint(resultTTest))
```
````

### PDF Result

[image: PDF result]

## PDF and HTML

If you really need the page work in both cases PDF and HTML, the tidyPrint should be a little different in the last step.

````
```r
tidyPrint <- function(data) {
    content <- paste0(data,collapse = "\n\n")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\t","    ")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\ ","\\\\ ")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\$","\\\\$")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,"\\*","\\\\*")
    content <- str_replace_all(content,":",": ")
    return(paste("<code>",content,"</code>\n"))
  }
```
````

### Result

The PDF result is the same, and the HTML result is close to the previous, but with some extra border.

[image: HTML Result in the mixed version]

It is not perfect but maybe is good enough.