# How to embed and escape R Markdown code in a R Markdown document

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I'm trying to write a memo on R Markdown syntax and as such I'd like to include in the document's output the R Markdown code **and** the output.

To be clear, I'd like the *output* to look something like:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Including the following code chunk in the document:

````
```{r, eval=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```
````

will produce the following output:

```
summary(cars)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I'm failing to escape the ```` ``` ```` **and** the `{r, eval=FALSE}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you evaluate this:

````
```{r comment=NA}
cat("```{r, eval=FALSE}\nsummary(cars)\n```")
```
````

Comment: Actually it prints `##` in front of every line as an R eval result. It's okay but ideally I'd like to show it as just a code chunk

Comment: Actually the answer to this question finishes it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081212/remove-hashes-in-r-output-from-rmarkdown-and-knitr