# How do I escape an RMarkdown chunk?

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to render the syntax for chunks of code in RMarkdown to a pdf. The final output should look like

````
```{r}
#some code
```
````

Rather than just

```
#some code
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best options to answer this can be found on the RStudio website. See the article on getting verbatim R chunks into rmarkdown http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_verbatim.html

My preferred solution is to add an inline R code at the end of the first line to make the chunk appear correctly in the output like so:

````
```{r eval=TRUE}` r ''`
seq(1, 10)
```
````

Which produces

````
```{r eval=TRUE}
seq(1:10)
```
````

Rather than

```
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Another way to do the same thing is treat the code chunk as a string (I don't usually use the `->` operator but in this case I think this improves readability):

````
```{r comment = ""}
"{r eval=TRUE}
seq(1, 10)
" -> my_code_string

cat("```", my_code_string, "```", sep = "")
```
````

Which outputs:

````
```{r eval=TRUE}
seq(1, 10)
```
````

This question is also a possible duplicate of [How to embed and escape R Markdown code in a R Markdown document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29509274/8475145)